# How to configure Docker volumes in SpringBoot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, file-upload, docker-volume

I have an apllication where user can upload photos to server (in localhost without Docker it works without problems, I can open images via link in borwser without autentication, authorization).
When I'm starting my application on Docker, when user try to upload photo to server, the photo uploaded only in container to folder `masterclass-photos`. And the folder `/var/lib/public/images` where I expecting to see a photo - is empty.

**How to configure docker to have access to photos just like when running on localhost?**

Project structure. Folders `masterclass-photos` and `motherforum-data` are created by docker.
[image]

Also I have a logs:

```
2022-11-23 12:18:31 java.net.UnknownHostException: masterclass-photos
2022-11-23 12:18:31     at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(NioSocketImpl.java:567) ~[na:na]
2022-11-23 12:18:31     at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:633) ~[na:na]
2022-11-23 12:18:31     at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.doConnect(FtpClient.java:1045) ~[na:na]
2022-11-23 12:18:31     at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.tryConnect(FtpClient.java:1010) ~[na:na]
2022-11-23 12:18:31     at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1102) ~[na:na]
2022-11-23 12:18:31     at java.base/sun.net.ftp.impl.FtpClient.connect(FtpClient.java:1088) ~[na:na]
...
...
a lot of line of stacktrace
ru.rcitsakha.motherforum.filter.CustomAuthorizationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomAuthorizationFilter.java:73) ~[classes!/:1.0-SNAPSHOT]
...
...
a lot of line of stacktrace
```

CustomAuthorizationFilter class, which are figured in logs

```
package ru.rcitsakha.motherforum.filter;

import com.auth0.jwt.JWT;
import com.auth0.jwt.JWTVerifier;
import com.auth0.jwt.algorithms.Algorithm;
import com.auth0.jwt.interfaces.DecodedJWT;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.servlet.FilterChain;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import static java.util.Arrays.stream;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION;
import static org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.FORBIDDEN;
import static org.springframework.http.MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE;

@Slf4j
public class CustomAuthorizationFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {
    private String jwtSecret;

    public void setJwtSecret(String jwtSecret) {
        this.jwtSecret = jwtSecret;
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
                                    HttpServletResponse response,
                                    FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        if (request.getServletPath().equals("/api/login") || request.getServletPath().equals("/api/token/refresh/**")) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
        } else {
            String authorizationHeader = request.getHeader(AUTHORIZATION);
            if (authorizationHeader != null && authorizationHeader.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
                try {
                    String token = authorizationHeader.substring("Bearer ".length());
                    Algorithm algorithm = Algorithm.HMAC256(jwtSecret.getBytes()); // should be same with authenticationFilter
                    JWTVerifier verifier = JWT.require(algorithm).build();
                    DecodedJWT decodedJWT = verifier.verify(token);
                    String username = decodedJWT.getSubject();
                    String[] roles = decodedJWT.getClaim("roles").asArray(String.class);
                    Collection<SimpleGrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<>();
                    stream(roles).forEach(role -> {
                        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(role));
                    });
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken =
                            new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null, authorities);
                    SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
                    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
                } catch (Exception exception) {
                    log.error("Error logging in: {}", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setHeader("error", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setStatus(FORBIDDEN.value());

                    Map<String, String> error = new HashMap<>();
                    error.put("error_message", exception.getMessage());
                    response.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE);
                    new ObjectMapper().writeValue(response.getOutputStream(), error);
                }
            } else {
                filterChain.doFilter(request, response); // line 73 from logs
            }
        }
    }
}
```

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:15'
    container_name: 'java-postgres'
    env_file:
      - config/.envfile
    volumes:
      - ./motherforum-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data


  app:
    build: ./
    container_name: 'java-app'
    environment:
      - 'PORT=8080'
      - 'SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/motherforumdb'
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    depends_on:
      - postgres
    volumes:
      - ./masterclass-photos:/var/lib/public/images
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:17
ADD /target/mother-forum-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar backend.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "/backend.jar"]
```

Here I setting resource handler

```
package ru.rcitsakha.motherforum.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

@Configuration
public class MvcConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        exposeDirectory("masterclass-photos", registry);
    }

    private void exposeDirectory(String dirName, ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        Path uploadDir = Paths.get(dirName);
        String uploadPath = uploadDir.toFile().getAbsolutePath();

        if (dirName.startsWith("../")) {
            dirName = dirName.replace("../", "");
        }

        registry.addResourceHandler("/" + dirName + "/**")
                .addResourceLocations("file:/" + uploadPath + "/");
    }
}
```

Postman request (), where in JSON body we can see the link of image. This endpoint don't require JWT because of `http.authorizeHttpRequests().antMatchers("/api/login/**", "/token/refresh", "api/motherforum/**").permitAll();`

[image]

Folder `masterclass-photos/3` don't creating on server file system. But it is created inside container.

[image]

And the folder `/var/lib/public/images`, where I expect see the foto is empty

[image]

Mount of my java application container

```
 "Mounts": [
            {
                "Type": "bind",
                "Source": "C:\\ProdApps\\mother-forum\\masterclass-photos",
                "Destination": "/var/lib/public/images",
                "Mode": "rw",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            }
        ]
```

MasterClass class, which contains path to photos. Maybe I need change here the method `getPhotosImagePath()` ?

```
package ru.rcitsakha.motherforum.model;


import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore;
import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

@Entity
@Table(name = "masterclass")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
public class MasterClass {

    private static final String DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;

    private String title;

    @Column(length = 2000)
    private String description;

    private String address;

    private String dateTime;

    private boolean isExpired;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.PERSIST,
                    CascadeType.MERGE
            })
    @JoinTable(
            name = "masterclass_mother",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "masterclass_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "mother_id")
    )
    @ToString.Exclude
    @JsonIgnore
    private Set<Mother> mothers = new HashSet<>();

    public void addMother(Mother mother) {
        this.mothers.add(mother);
        mother.getMasterClasses().add(this);
    }

    @Column(length = 128)
    @ElementCollection
    private List<String> photos = new ArrayList<>();

    public void removeMother(long motherId) {
        Mother mother = this.mothers.stream()
                .filter(m -> m.getId() == motherId)
                .findFirst()
                .orElse(null);

        if (mother != null) {
            this.mothers.remove(mother);
            mother.getMasterClasses().remove(this);
        }
    }

    public void copy(MasterClass masterClass) {
        this.title = masterClass.title;
        this.description = masterClass.description;
        this.address = masterClass.address;
        this.dateTime = masterClass.dateTime;
        this.isExpired = masterClass.isExpired;
    }

    @Transient
    public List<String> getPhotosImagePath() {
        if (photos == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return photos.stream()
                .map(photoFileName -> "/masterclass-photos/" + id + "/" + photoFileName)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
}
```

Comment: Your docker config maps the directory `masterclass-photos` on your host to `/var/lib/public/images` in the docker container.  For the container to write a file that you'll then see on your host, it has to write to `/var/lib/public/images`, or some subdir of that dir.  I don't see that you're doing that.  I see that you refer to `masterclass-photos` in your code, but if that code is running in the container, that name has nothing to do with the fact that a directory with that name on the host is mapped to `/var/lib/public/images`.  You need to be writing to `/var/lib/public/images`.

Comment: Should I make some changes like this? 
@Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        exposeDirectory("/var/lib/public/imagess", registry);
    }